# Change text in Eclipse at compile

Tags: eclipse, macros, replace

I want to be able to write for example ((DATE)) in Eclipse and have it replaced with the current date when compiled. How to accomplish this?

The idea is to use dates in version numbers, so I could have the program output stuff like 1.0.2012.01.13

Edit: Language is Java and platform is Android

Comment: Java or some other language? Eclipse supports many?

Comment: Well, Java doesn't natively support macros like that, but possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003410/displaying-the-build-time-stamp-in-an-application ? For what it's worth, personally, I use Subversion "$Rev:$" and friends for this purpose.

Comment: I found the same "rgagnon" page mentioned in your link BRPocock, but it seems like a lot for such a simple thing. Subversion variables aren't sufficient, I want the build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done unless you templatize your code using something like Velocity, which is going to be much more trouble than it's worth. Factor these strings out into .properties files and generate those, perhaps.