# How do i change NetBeans build time from seconds to milliseconds or nanoseconds?

Tags: java, netbeans, time, build

Title says it all. I need to compare 2 small classes that are similar in ram usage and size and they have the same build time in seconds, but i need that time in milliseconds (no "convert from seconds to milliseconds formula", i need to know how many exact milliseconds passed).

Comment: You need to compare the _build_ time?   Why?  Are you sure you wouldn't be more interested in comparing _run_ times?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Re _"You need to compare the build time? Why?"_, by default NetBeans will round the build time of a project to the nearest second. On my machine any small project will typically build in less than half a second, and NetBeans will unhelpfully report "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)". The question being asked is a good one, and I'd like to know the answer myself.

Comment: See [Displaying the build time-stamp in an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003410/displaying-the-build-time-stamp-in-an-application) for possible solutions for both Ant and Maven projects. If you install the Groovy plugin then your project will be built using Gradle, and the displayed build time includes fractions of a second (e.g. _BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 3.755 secs_)

Comment: @skomisa thank you. I will check that out tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is there any option for that.
You can use the below code to find build time by adding few lines into the main() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   final long START = System.nanoTime();

   //YOUR CODE HERE...

   final long END = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("Time taken : " + ((END - START) / 1e+9) + " seconds");

}
```

> Time taken : 0.05408 seconds

**I hope it might help someone :)**

Answer (score 0):

I use: `System.currentTimeMillis();` 
 Here's an example just to clear things

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    //Store starting time

    /*
    CODE HERE
    */

    System.out.println("Time taken : " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) + " millisecond(s)." );
}
```